# Disable onscreenControl in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

is it possible to remove or disable the AnalogOnScreenControl from the HUD? I found no method in the class HUD or AnalogOnScreenControl that manages this case.

I have a box with an onTouchArea that appears when text is shown on the screen, when this happens I set the AnalogOnScreenControl invisible. But it is still there, so the box doesn't register the touch in the area where the AnalogOnScreenControl is.

The AnalogOnScreenControl is set with hud.setChildScene(analogOnScreenControl) and the box is a child of hud.

Every suggestion helps. =)

Greetings, Merlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to disable

```
analogOnScreenControl.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
```

to remove

```
hud.clearChildScene();
```